# redirection of own domain & addon domain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my domain name is domain1.com

my addon domain is domain2.com

In the domain2.com root folder, I've the .htaccess & sitemap.xml file with content below.

### .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain1.com/$1 [NC,P]
```

My changed coding in .htacess
Now I'm changing this coding in .htacess
http://domain2.dk/.htaccess file content is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain1.dk/$1 [NC,P]
```

Now http://domain2.dk/sitemap.xml is working fine what I'm expecting.. But http://domain2.dk/ is not working...

### .sitemap.xml

> http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">    http://www.domain2.com/
>   2016-07-26T18:58:09+00:00
>   weekly   1.00 
>      http://www.domain2.com/login
>   2016-07-26T18:58:09+00:00
>   weekly   0.80

In the domain1.com root folder, I've sitemap.xml file with content below.

### .sitemap.xml

> http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">    http://www.domain1.com/
>   2016-07-26T18:58:09+00:00
>   weekly   1.00
>
> http://www.domain1.com/login
>   2016-07-26T18:58:09+00:00
>   weekly   0.80

domain1.com has .htaccess file also sitemap.xml file
www.domain2.com also has .htaccess file also sitemap.xml file

This is my need:

domain1.com/sitemap.xml - sitemap.xml should come from domain1.com

www.domain2.com/sitemap.xml - sitemap.xml should come from domain2.com
other files are come from domain1.com

can I get any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to proxy? Can't you serve both of these domains from the same location and then have just a simple rewrite rule to show different sitemap for each of them?

Comment: can you pls explain, now what do I do?

Comment: Are the domains on the same server?

Comment: yes, both are in same server

Comment: @Erki A, yes, both are in same server

Comment: @Erki A, you can see in detail, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849078/redirection-issue-with-sitemap-xml-using-htaccess